# Need the second firebase query to start after the first ends javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in javascript and recently I've been working on a project and in this project  I'm trying to save initial score in an empty firebase database which works perfectly fine. However just as the score is saved I want to retrieve it and do some calculations on it. I've tried `setTimeout` but it didn't work. Btw if there are scores in the firebase already it's working fine.

This is my code and thanks in advance:

```
function resultOne() {
var firstScore = trim(newGroup[0]);

scores(firstScore);

setTimeout(function() {return true;}, 30000);
var firstguyScore = getScore(firstScore)
console.log(firstGuyScore);
}
```

This is a function to set the initial score of 1500 and set name....

```
function scores(firstGuy) {
// Firebase query to increment the chosen girl and her seen status by 1 and to initialize each score by 1500
let ref = firebase.database().ref("scores");
let query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(firstGuy);
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
      let userRef = userSnapshot.ref;
      userRef.child("chosen").transaction((currentValue) => {
        return currentValue + 1;
      });

      userRef.child("seen").transaction((currentValue) => {
        return currentValue + 1;
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    ref.push({
      name: firstGuy,
      chosen: 1,
      seen: 1,
      score: 1500
    });
  }
});
```

and this is a function to retreive the data

```
async function getScore(firstGuy) {

  let ref = firebase.database().ref("scores");
  let query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(firstGuy);
  const snapshot = await query.once("value")
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        var userData = userSnapshot.val();
        score = userData.score;
        console.log(score);
      });
    }
  
}
```

Comment: `once()` returns a promise,  I suggest using that instead of the callback parameter in your scores function, and also make scores return a promise that resolves when the work is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` calls the function (callback) you provide after a certain time. It does not block and wait. Your call to `getScores()` is executed immediately, as you can see in the console.

You can change the code as follows:

```js
function resultOne() {
  const firstScore = trim(newGroup[0]);

  scores(firstScore);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const firstguyScore = getScore(firstScore);
    console.log(firstGuyScore);
  }, 30000);
}
```

Using `setTimeout()` this way is okay for testing and debugging. You should not use it this way in your production-ready code.

Why not `await` on `scores()` as well?

```
async function scores(firstGuy) {
  ...
  const snapshot = await query.once("value");
  ...
}

async function resultOne() {
  const firstScore = trim(newGroup[0]);
  await scores(firstScore);
  const firstguyScore = await getScore(firstScore);
  console.log(firstGuyScore);
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats working however you said this is okay for debugging and testing. May you recommend a better way for my production ready code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `setTimeout()` with an arbitrary timeout because there is no "correct" timeout. The timeout will be either too long, wasting time or too short, leading to errors. Using Promises and async/await is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie. If you may help me a little with the promises?

Comment: I suggest you read or watch an introduction or tutorial on Promises, like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). If you run into specific problems or issues, StackOverflow usually has answers or you can post a new question.